# Octopus client cannot parse Deployments dict in ReleaseProgressionResource

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json-deserialization, octopus-deploy

I am trying to get release progressions for a certain project using the Octopus Client ([github source](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctopusClients)) calling the `/api/progression/<project-id>` endpoint like this:

```
// _repository is of type IOctopusRepository 
_repository.Client.Get<ProgressionResource>($"/api/progression/{projectId}");
```

Which is immediately throwing an `OctopusDeserializationException` saying:

> Unable to process response from server: Cannot deserialize the current
>   JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[Octopus.Client.Model.DashboardItemResource]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>       To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.
>       Path 'Releases[0].Deployments.Environments-1.Id', line 55, position 15.. Response content: {
>         "Environments": [
>           {
>             "Id": "Environments-1",
>             "Name": "test-environment"
>           },

In each Release (of type `ReleaseProgressionResource`) from the `Releases`there is a `Deployments` prop which is of type `Dictionary<string,IOrderedEnumerable<DashboardItemResource>>`. However, it seems like the client (that has been made to consume this API) cannot serialize that. From the exception message, it seems like the client is trying to parse that as a JSON array.

Here's a sample `Deployments` part of the endpoint response in raw JSON (with some dummy data):

```
"Deployments": {
        "Environments-1": {
          "Id": "Deployments-12345",
          "ProjectId": "Projects-123",
          "EnvironmentId": "Environments-1",
          "ReleaseId": "Releases-12345",
          "DeploymentId": "Deployments-12345",
          "TaskId": "ServerTasks-12345",
          "ReleaseVersion": "5.4.3",
          "Created": "2016-09-22T21:26:38.886+00:00",
          "QueueTime": "2016-09-22T21:26:38.855+00:00",
          "CompletedTime": "2016-09-22T21:29:48.355+00:00",
          "State": "Success",
          "HasPendingInterruptions": false,
          "HasWarningsOrErrors": false,
          "ErrorMessage": "",
          "Duration": "3 minutes",
          "IsCurrent": true,
          "IsPrevious": false,
          "IsCompleted": true,
          "Links": {
            "Self": "/api/deployments/Deployments-12345",
            "Release": "/api/releases/Releases-12345",
            "Task": "/api/tasks/ServerTasks-12345"
          }
        }
 }
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be happening/what I might be doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the whole Deployment object? JSON objects need to be enclosed in brackets.

```
{
    "Deployments": {
        "Environments-1": {
            "Id": "Deployments-12345",
            "ProjectId": "Projects-123",
            "EnvironmentId": "Environments-1",
            "ReleaseId": "Releases-12345",
            "DeploymentId": "Deployments-12345",
            "TaskId": "ServerTasks-12345",
            "ReleaseVersion": "5.4.3",
            "Created": "2016-09-22T21:26:38.886+00:00",
            "QueueTime": "2016-09-22T21:26:38.855+00:00",
            "CompletedTime": "2016-09-22T21:29:48.355+00:00",
            "State": "Success",
            "HasPendingInterruptions": false,
            "HasWarningsOrErrors": false,
            "ErrorMessage": "",
            "Duration": "3 minutes",
            "IsCurrent": true,
            "IsPrevious": false,
            "IsCompleted": true,
            "Links": {
                "Self": "/api/deployments/Deployments-12345",
                "Release": "/api/releases/Releases-12345",
                "Task": "/api/tasks/ServerTasks-12345"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No that's just the part where it is failing to serialize. It's a part of a bigger structure. I fetch `ProgressionResource`, which has a colection of `ReleaseProgressionResources` which amongst other things has this `Deployments` dictionary which fails to deserialize, as the deserializer is trying to parse it as an object with a property named `Environments-1` instead of as a dict.